# Cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to implement expression tree with linq.I am getting error state as cannot convert lambdaexpression to expression. Please help i checked other solution but couldn't help as much ! Below is my code

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");
var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(pe, sortByProp), pe);        
          var d=  expr.Compile();
            IQueryable<Person> query = persons.AsQueryable();
            List<Person> sortedList = query.OrderBy<Person, int>(expr).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the property you want to sort by ?

Comment: what do you want to implement using this expression tree?

Comment: The post title is misleading, because the last part of the error is not just `Expression`, but `Expression<Func<Person, int>>`, which is different. How do you know the `sortByProp` **type** is `int`?

Comment: I want to sort by age property of Person class which is int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to implement OrderBy dynamically using expression trees. You should try the following:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var typeArguments = new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType };
    var methodName = sortOrder == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, typeArguments, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

and then you can call it as:

```
collection.OrderBy("Property on which you want to sort", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment:  It looks like you are trying to implement OrderBy dynamically using expression trees. Would you like help? – Clippy

Comment: I resolved this with help of Awais answer but you have any more approach definitely will love to see it!